# Switch between workspaces with mouse (not trackpad / magicpad and not keyboard)

Tags: mouse, mission-control

Is there a way I can switch between workspaces with a mouse?

I know I can configure keyboard shortcuts for this, and I can also configure trackpad 3/4 finger swipe up for mission control then select workspace from there.

But is there a method for switching workspaces with only mouse?

Comment: What type of mouse? I know Apples Bluetooth mouse can do the exact thing you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, use the mouse to click on Mission Control in the dock and then click on your space. It takes 2 clicks but still pretty quick!

Answer (score 0):

Better Touch Tool allows you to trigger actions through mouse clicks. That ought to solve the problem. According to their [website](https://folivora.ai/):

> BetterTouchTool is a great, feature packed app that allows you to customize various input devices on your Mac.
> Currently BetterTouchTool supports: ... Normal Mouse Buttons

Here's a [link](https://docs.folivora.ai/docs/801_normal_mice.html) to some documentation on mouse actions.